# Xamarin.Forms use Flyout/Menu Item as header and customize BG Color and Text Color

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

In my shell application flyout menu, I would like to have header items which are simply text. They must be non-clickable and customizable (most important part I'm trying to figure out is the customizable part).

Including this code in my MainShell.xaml page causes the items to appear, but I cannot figure out how to customize the way they look (I would like "Parent" and "Student" to have different bg color and text color).

```
<MenuItem Text="Parent"/>

<FlyoutItem Title="Lobby">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Lobby}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Announcements">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Announcements}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<MenuItem Text="Student"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you mean that want to set a background color for `MenuItem` in 
a **Xamarin Forms Shell** application?

Comment: I would like to do that, but also change the way the font looks, make the MenuItem non-clickable, and also have the text all the way to the left (no icon margin).

Comment: Okey, I have updated an answer, you can have a look when you have time.If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Shell.MenuItemTemplate` that can **[Define MenuItem appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-menuitem-appearance)**, then you can custom a MenuItem with different background color and text color.

For example:

```
<MenuItem>
    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="Custom MenuItem"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   FontFamily="Montserrat-Regular"
                   BackgroundColor="LightBlue" 
                   TextColor="Brown"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

The effect:

[image]